# Rider. Пустой .cs файл при генерации из web-reference

Tags: c#, wcf, jetbrains, rider, onvif

Когда я добавляю web-reference к https://www.onvif.org/ver10/pacs/accesscontrol.wsdl Rider создает пустой .cs файл. Может кто-нибудь подсказать в чем дело?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте пересобрать проект, возможно это поможет сгенерировать файл заново.

Если это не поможет и вы используете .Net Core, то можно сгенерировать файл с использованием командной строки и svcutil

Сначала установите тул из командой строки:

`dotnet tool install --global dotnet-svcutil`

После установки сгенерируйте файл:

`dotnet-svcutil.exe https://www.onvif.org/ver10/pacs/accesscontrol.wsdl -o AccessControl.cs`

По результату получите папку `ServiceReference` содержащую файл `AccessControl.cs`, который можно будет добавить к себе в проект.